# Embed Instagram photo using Pusher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, instagram, pusher

In my application I use [Pusher](https://pusher.com/) in order to publish content in realtime.
Recently I added Instagram content, which is published also via Pusher. It means that without reloading the page, an Instagram entry might appear.

I use the embed code Instagram supplies:

```
<blockquote class="instagram-media"  .....
    :
    :
```

Usually there is no problem. But from time to time I get the content without the image, and instead a gray camera icon:
[image]

**When I refresh page, usually I can see the photo.**

Looking for some hint in console, this is what I got under *Network* tab:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Any clues in the browser console? Check the network tab also.

Comment: How large are these images? Pusher only supports events whose body is under 10kB.

Comment: No clue in console @max, I have just added a screenshot of it.

Comment: @will-sewell, I don't think it has something to do, Pusher only send the html code, not the image itself.

Comment: @guyaloni it would be worth also checking the Pusher console on https://dashboard.pusher.com/. You could then [turn on debug logging on pusher.js](https://pusher.com/docs/debugging#pusher_logging) which will show output in the browser console. Then you could check where the events stop sending.

Comment: I checked Pusher console, even copied the html to a static html page and checked it in browser and I can see the image. So I suspect it has to do with Instagram mode then Pusher.